# PHP preg_match part of string efficiently

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

For example, given the following function definition:

```
function match($subject, $pattern, $offset);
```

These tests should succeed:

```
$subject = "23 is a number, so is 10";

match($subject, '[0-9]+', 0) == '23';
match($subject, '[0-9]+', 3) == false;
match($subject, '[0-9]+', 6) == false;
match($subject, '[0-9]+', 8) == false;

match($subject, '[a-z]+', 0) == false;
match($subject, '[a-z]+', 3) == 'is';
match($subject, '[a-z]+', 6) == 'a';
match($subject, '[a-z]+', 8) == 'number';
```

One possible way is to match a substring starting at `$offset` by using `^`:

```
function match($subject, $pattern, $offset) {

    if (preg_match("/^($pattern)/", substr($subject, offset), $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }

    return false;
}
```

This would make a copy of a the string, which ofcourse isn't efficient for large strings.

Another possible way to implement `match` would be:

```
function match($subject, $pattern, $offset) {

    if (preg_match("/($pattern)/", $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)) {
        if ($matches[1][1] == $offset) {
            return $matches[1][0];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But this would keep trying to match even if the first character mismatches.

**Question**:
How can I match a part of a string efficiently?

Or maybe better, is it possible to assert the offset position? Like `^` would assert the start of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that, see the second implementation. It isn't efficient.

Comment: But it is correct, and that is how you should be doing that in my opinion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True, but I need it to start matching from the offset, so that it is efficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: no it isn't because even with the offset parameter, `^` matches always the start of the string and not the offset position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function match($subject, $pattern, $offset) {
    if (preg_match('/^.{' . $offset . '}\K' . $pattern . '/us', $subject, $match))
        return $match[0];
    return false;
}
```

---

Better! You can use the `\G` anchor that matches at the offset:

```
function match($subject, $pattern, $offset) {
    if (preg_match('/\G' . $pattern . '/us', $subject, $match, 0, $offset))
        return $match[0];
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! A side from that, I was wondering why you'd use `us`?

Comment: @Tim: u is used to read both the string and the pattern as UTF8 encoded strings *(otherwise something like `.` may match a single byte instead of a multibyte character)*, and s to handle eventual patterns with `.` that is able to match the newline character.